# How should i use data that i fetch from webserver, in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to show data which i fetch from rest webservice (spring), in list(RecyclerView). Data can consist of thousands of rows. How should i use these data ?

- should i fetch all data(or 100 rows ) and store them in local and read them from local to view in list. if i use these , how should i refresh local data ?
- should i fetch 20 rows and view them , when user scroll down and arrive last item , i fetch another 20 rows ?
- or should i use another way ?
  If i store all data as array , it can throw outofmemoryexception . are there any tutorial or key words to search ?

How twitter or instagram use these data ? There can be a lot of items in twitter list ,but it doesn't crash and twitter can show items which downloaded before, offline(it means store data in local ,isnt' it ?)

Comment: I would suggest loading an initial amount of data (i.e. 20 rows) into your recyclerView, either implement an automatic load listener i.e. when the users reaches the bottom of visible items fetch more data or you could use a SwipeRefreshLayout to load more data.

Answer (score 1):

To make app work smoother with RecyclerView, use [Endless Scrolling](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView).
Load 20 items at a time, apply pagination on your server API call.

Cache every response from server to local storage using [OKHttp Response Caching](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CacheResponse.java).

Comment: Endless scrolling looks well and it works for fetching data and adding to list. But what should i do with old items and how to use them ? If i add items that i fetch ,  to list(i use ArrayList to set recyleview)  , list become biger and biger. should i clear list and add new items to list?  Also should i know that  user scroll up and arrive first item which is visible ? to add old items from local(cache or somewhere)  to list ?

Comment: You don't need to worry about the size of list, if you fetching results from cached data then it will work fine, because cached data loads faster and uses less resources. 

If you are not clearing old data from list then you don't need to keep track of user's scroll position. RecyclerView adapter will manage it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local database, store all data you already loaded inside the DB and add a "freshness" like a timestamp if your data is subject to change. If your data items are huge, consider loading an "index" of your data first, then load the individual details later.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should not fetch all the data at once. Read about Pagination for dynamic data in android. Recycler View also uses inbuilt pagination for static data but in case of dynamic data i.e. when you are retrieving data from your api, you should send requests to your api when the user scrolls down the list to fetch the next set of data. In order to do that you'll have to extend RecyclerView's OnScrollListener and override the OnScrolled method.